# Should I upgrade this Motorola MC5040 from PocketPC 2003 to Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Motorola MC5040 that was purchased through a liquidator... and we want to use it in our factory to access a simple web-app.  So all I really need to do is get it hooked into our WiFi... it connects to the access point, but I cannot get it to register an IP address (all other devices are getting IP addresses just fine)

- I could monkey with this thing until I figure out how to get the IP address to get assigned via WiFi... time is $$...
- try to upgrade it to a newer version of Windows Mobile (can it handle a it?)
- go buy a new model that is up to date

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a static IP on the device? It's pretty unlikely to work, but won't take long to try.

I assume that the device supports the required security protocols for the WiFi... Looking at the user manual it seems to support all the usual suspects.

I don't think there is an upgrade path for the device, and if there was there's no guarantee it would work, so I think it's down to monkeying around or buying a current device that's got manufacturer support on it.